# Syntax for accessing the requestScope attributes using EL

Tags: jsp, el

This post is a [followup to an earlier post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59803700/accessing-the-requestscope-attributes-using-el).

In my servlet class I am setting a request attribute, as follows:
`request.setAttribute("emperor", "Naruhito");`

In my JSP, the EL implicit object **requestScope** evaluates to the following value:
`{javax.servlet.forward.context_path=/newbie_jsp, javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path=/HomeServlet, javax.servlet.forward.request_uri=/newbie_jsp/HomeServlet, emperor=Naruhito}`

The syntax for extracting the **emperor** attribute in my JSP is `${requestScope.emperor}`

However, the syntax for extracting the **javax.servlet.forward.request_uri** attribute in my JSP is `${requestScope['javax.servlet.forward.request_uri']}`

---

Q) Why is there an apparent discrepancy between the two?

Answer (score 0):

The request parameter **javax.servlet.forward.request_uri**, that is defined in the Servlet/JSP specification and is automatically populated, contains ‘.’ In its name :
In that case, you need to use the 
`${requestScope['Param']}`
 (aka “bracket”) syntax.

Your custom **emperor** param doesn’t contains a dot (‘.’), so you can use the short notation:
`${requestScope.param}`

Hope that will help, 
Regards, Cedric